# Track user location globally in flutter (at background too)

Tags: flutter, location, tracking

I need to track user location at background in every screen of my app, i already implemented a method to take location with geolocator package, but it only works if i put the code in every app screen. Is it possible in flutter?

ps.: i tried to use workmanager, but the minimum interval is 15 minutes, and i need to receive the location in an interval of 3 seconds.

my actually code bellow:

```
getPosicaoAtual() async {
    try {
      Position posicao = await _posicaoAtual();
      DbUtil.insert('local', {
        'latitude': posicao.latitude,
        'longitude': posicao.longitude,
      });
      _local = {
        'latitude': posicao.latitude,
        'longitude': posicao.longitude,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      clearLocal();
      _local['erro'] = e.toString();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<Position> _posicaoAtual() async {
    LocationPermission permissao;
    // Location location = new Location();
    bool ativado = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!ativado) {
      // await location.requestService();
      if (!await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled()) {
        return Future.error('Por favor, habilite a localização no smartphone');
      }
    }

    permissao = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permissao == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permissao = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permissao == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Você precisa autorizar o acesso à localização');
      }
    }

    if (permissao == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('-1');
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service
To run flutter code in background even app is terminated